# Ionic2 unit tests with rollup

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner, ionic2, rollup

I'm looking for a guide on unit tests for ionic2 rc3 sample app (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app)
I tried the http://lathonez.github.io/2016/ionic-2-unit-testing/ and worked perfectly,  but I'm trying to do it without angular-cli and use rollup.

Thanks